# Wordpress website giving 404

Tags: plugins, urls, 404-error

Hey a friend of mine was having trouble with a wordpress website and all pages other then home pages keep giving a 404 error.

- look at the php admin database and wp_options are pointing to the
  right website.
- so i look at the htaccess and it looks fine (here is whats in it)

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

Tried resetting the permalinks and still 404.

So any ideas what could be causing this ? 
update: its not a new site or has it moved server.
here is the link wantajob.ie  anyway.

Comment: Is it a live or development website? Because im seeing a rewriteBase /dev/

Comment: Do you see the WordPress theme 404, or the server's 404 page? If you see the server's 404 page, the problem is further upstream than WordPress.

Comment: @Milo the theme does not have a 404 page.

Comment: when were the troubles visible? dit you moved the website? update a plugin? or wordpress?

Comment: That's not important, if it's the server's 404 page, the problem is higher up than WordPress. If it looks at all like the theme, meaning WordPress is loading, then the problem is WordPress.

Comment: `mod_rewrite` isn't working or your .htaccess file isn't being parsed, requests for internal pages are not being directed to WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this .htaccess.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
```

Comment: ok i added it , still getting 404